# Geometric Intuition for the Moyal Product

Tags: quantum-mechanics, phase-space, poisson-brackets, deformation-quantization

I've recently been reading into deformation quantization as another formulation of quantum mechanics. I have focused on understanding the Moyal product in particular, as it contains the seeds for the non-classical behavior of the theory. I understand the mathematics and how to apply the definitions, but I am confused by the interpretation of the product physically.

I couldn't make much sense of the "meaning" of the differential definitions, nor could I find my answers in the shift formulas. However, the integral definitions of the product have begun to make more sense to me. In particular, I was reading [a paper that defined the product in one-dimension as](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pgiq/1434145475)

$$(f★g)(r) = \int\int f(r_1)g(r_2)\exp\left[{\frac{4i}{\hbar}A(r, r_1, r_2)}\right]dr_1\wedge dr_2$$

where $r, r_1, r_2$ all denote points in phase space $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $A$ is the area of the triangle made by these three points. This is much easier for me to interpret compared to the exponential of derivative operators. Still, the physical meaning of these triangles in phase-space, and why their areas are mapped to the unit circle is beyond me.

I was wondering if anyone had any useful ways of interpreting the Moyal product through whatever definition they find easiest to wrap their head around. Any direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76494/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I Assume you have read up on the original formulation, "Geometrical evaluation of star products", C Zachos (2000), 
*Journal of Mathematical Physics*  **41** 5129 ,  https://doi.org/10.1063/1.533395