# Classical limit of Moyal bracket in integral representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, phase-space, semiclassical, wigner-transform, deformation-quantization

It is well-known that the Poisson bracket can be recovered out of the Moyal bracket under the limit when $\hbar$ goes to zero $$\lim_{\hbar\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{i\hbar} \lbrace f,g\rbrace_M=\lbrace f,g \rbrace_P.$$
This is easy to verify in the differential form of the brackets, but the Moyal bracket admit an integral representation as
$$\lbrace f,g\rbrace_M=\frac{2}{\hbar^3\pi^2}\int dp' dp'' dq' dq'' f(x+x',p+p')g(x+x',p+p')\sin(\frac{2}{\hbar}(x'p''-x''p')).$$
How to recover an integral form of the Poisson bracket performing the limit here?

Comment: The integral representation is equivalent to the differential form, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/76494/2451) Phys.SE post, so essentially nothing left to prove.

Comment: Obviously, the aim is not to prove that a classical limit exists but more to find an integral expression for the Poisson bracket from the integral form of Moyal, as I stated it in the question.

Comment: Wouldn't that just produce the standard formula $(df/dx) (dg/dp)-(df/dp) (dg/dx)$ for the PB?

Comment: I’m not familiar with the standard integral formula for the Poisson bracket, do you have any reference for that?

Comment: Crossposted to https://mathoverflow.net/q/445419/13917